# F16-F19 keys on my keyboard in OBS as record start, stop, pause and resume buttons

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I would like to use the F16-F19 keys on my keyboard in OBS as record start, stop, pause and resume buttons. How do I do this? In OBS they are recognized correctly, but when I press them to record they are no longer recognized. It seems that they are intercepted by another program. What can I do?

Comment: Where are these set up? In OBS prefs? If so, they would probably only be active whilst OBS is the front-most app.

Comment: That's exactly how it is. As soon as OBS is active, they work. But that was different from the previous version. Looks like a bug to me. Hopefully, this will be fixed soon.

Comment: Ah, OK. I'd maybe make sure OBS are aware of it then. Give their support channels a try.

Answer (score 0):

It was because this checkbox was not set:

[image: This must be set for the hotkeys to work]